# Render different view dynamically in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

Is there any way in aurelia I can render different view dynamically.

```
  async Activate(booking) {
    //booking: is the route param
    const hasRecord = await this.service.RecordExists(booking);
    if (hasRecord) {
            map(booking,form);
    }
    return {
        //Render different template
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should try to tackle this issue in another way. Why would you want to navigate to a ViewModel and trigger its creation, just in order to not use it and load another ViewModel? Seems inefficient at best right?

Aurelia exposes pipelines on the router, you should do this check there and redirect accordingly. Look at the PreActivate step [here](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/8), you could write something like this (pseudo code):

```
configureRouter(config, router) {
    function step() {
      return step.run;
    }
    step.run = async (navigationInstruction, next) => {
      if(await this.service.RecordExists(navigationInstruction.queryParams...)
      {
         return next()
      } else {
         next.cancel(new Redirect('your other page'))
      }
    };
    config.addPreActivateStep(step)
    config.map([
      { route: ['', 'home'],       name: 'home',       moduleId: 'home/index' },
      { route: 'users',            name: 'users',      moduleId: 'users/index',   nav: true },
      { route: 'users/:id/detail', name: 'userDetail', moduleId: 'users/detail' },
      { route: 'files/*path',       name: 'files',      moduleId: 'files/index',   href:'#files',   nav: true }
    ]);
  }
```

**EDIT**

You can have cases where you don't want a redirect, for example you have users wanting to bookmark baseurl/businessobject/id, and the url is navigatable before the object actually exists
Then you can use the `getViewStrategy()` function on your ViewModel:

```
getViewStrategy(){
    if(this.businessObj){
       return 'existingObjectView.html';     
    } else {
       return 'nonExisting.html';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, looking at your code. seems a redirect is happening hence changing url which is exactly what I want to avoid
 next.cancel(new Redirect('your other page')) .

Comment: Can you explain why you want to avoid a redirect? You can easily use 2 views with the same viewmodel, just provide 2 routes for it and you're set. You can solve your issue using the ```compose``` element, but it adds some complexity and I don't see the added value in your case

Comment: because, user should be able to bookmark this page, and in future this page may be available.

Comment: Does `getViewStrategy` work within CustomElements? The [docs](https://aurelia.io/docs/api/templating/interface/DynamicComponentGetViewStrategy/method/getViewStrategy/) seem to imply that only compose or router-elements can use it.

Comment: It doesn't, the docs are correct, see: https://github.com/aurelia/templating/issues/360